# Android ListView.addHeaderView flickers when adding ImageView

Tags: android, listview, imageview, flicker

I added an ImageView to a ListView via addHeaderView(image, null, false), so it is not selectable, but when I scroll the list, the imageview flickers(between image and black background), is there anything I can do to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will solve your problem but you could try calling `setCacheColorHint(0)` on  your ListView. What you describe sounds like what is covered in this article...[ListView Backgrounds](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html)